# What are correct file permissions?

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-management, rom-manager, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8, file-permissions

My phone is a Sony Ericsson Xperia X8, and I'm using CyanogenMod. There is an app called ROM Manager included in CyanogenMod, and I found an option 'Fix permission' there. I shouldn't have used this: I had no problems before but I have some now. During the fixing process I got a lot Force close dialogs, and after next reboot the phone had reset to the *default* CyanogenMod home screen configuration, *default* options for many programs, and *default* network parameter. I also got some more Force close dialogs.

I have a backup done a week ago, but I really installed a lot during the week, so I don't want to lose it all. I hope there's a way to recover current situation.

I tried this through adb shell:

```
chmod -R 755 /data/data
chmod -R 744 /system/app
```

but it didn't help.

I even tried this stupid idea:

```
chmod -R 777 /
```

but it made even worse: after reboot, my phone forgot even my Google account and offered to reconfigure it as if it was the first time I switch the phone after buying it.

Can somebody tell me which file/directory permissions could ROM Manager change and how should I restore them to make everything work? Currently I have a backup made immediately after I discovered the problem.

**UPDATE:** [This fix_permissions.sh](http://androidforums.com/g1-support/13657-fix_permissions.html) didn't work for me.

Comment: Try booting into recovery and resetting permissions there. IIRC it's in advanced.

Comment: I have «CWM-based Recovery v5.0.2.7» on «nAa kernel», and it doesn't have anything about permissions in the menu.

Comment: Well it should be there. Advanced -> Fix Permissions

Comment: I'm sure, it's not there. In Advanced, I have only «Reboot Recovery», «Wipe Dalvik Cache», «Wipe Battery Stats», «Report Error», «Key Test», «Show log», and nothing else. Hmm, should I reinstall/replace this recovery with another one?

Comment: Yes you should. I'm using the official version download through Rom Manager.

Comment: It asked me to confirm phone model. There was only one option — E15i (that's Xperia X8), I selected it, and it wrote «E15i does not have an officially supported ClockwordMod Recovery yet. Have you installed a ClockworkMod based recovery manually?»

Comment: I don't remember where did I got my current recovery.